# Why does Scabbers protect Ron and Harry by biting Goyle?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, when Malfoy, Crabe and Goyle are going to fight Harry and Ron, why does Scabbers protect them? After it is later shown in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* that Scabbers is in fact Peter Pettigrew who betrayed Potter's parents, why did he protect Ron and Harry?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate, they are asking why the trouble, I'm asking if it was something that slipped by Rowling when writing the books knowing that she is meticulous about what she puts in her books.

Comment: A rat would bite anyone that disturbs him not just Harry Potter's enemies

Comment: @Hannah, you read the Harry Potter series? Each book has no inconsistencies with itself, but each book is inconsistent with the books after and before it in at least one way. They have truth serum, and yet the innocent are guilty. Why was petigrew the secret keeper? when having Jame's do it would have been both easier and safer.